# How can I play a library item with four keyframes as a single animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, import, keyframe

I'm using AS3, and have one simple layer with 4 keyframes If I import it to another fla file as a library item, it keeps showing me all keyframes, I don't want that I want it to show me the whole animation.

Like, if I have an animation of me swinging a baseball bat, I don't want to see all the keyframes seperately imported into the library, but I want it to be all in one piece, so that when I click play it plays all keyframes.

Sorry if this is very noobish but i'm new at flash actionscripting.

I will appreciate any answer given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u should load the swf to other fla.for that u can use URLRequest and Loader.like:

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("2ndswf.swf"));

this wil load the the swf to the current fla.